# How to enable the stencil buffer in cocos2d-x v3.10?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've seen other posts on the web which say to do:

```
[__glview layoutSubviews];
```

But you can't do this in 3.10 - glView is a cocos2d-x pointer.

How do we enable it? I am trying to use UIScrollview, and the moment I do ui::ScrollView::create() , the console shows a message "Stencil buffer is not enabled" and the scroll view doesn't seem to display.

Answer (score 0):

You should override a method in your `AppDelegate` class.

```
  void AppDelegate::initGLContextAttrs()
  {
    //set OpenGL context attributions,now can only set six attributions:
    //red,green,blue,alpha,depth,stencil
    GLContextAttrs glContextAttrs = {8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8};

    GLView::setGLContextAttrs(glContextAttrs);
  }
```

Comment: my initGLContextAttrs() function is identical to yours. Is there some other change that has to be made ? My function was created by using "cocos new" - I did not modify it.

Comment: @John What's your test device? Is it on Android platform?

Comment: @John Try to use a real device to test it.

Comment: Also enabling stencil buffer size to non-zero reduce fps (im my case from 50 to 45, at some android platform. which can be too big for small piece of drawing).
So be careful and monitor your fps after every changes.